# Why do these two images not wanna go on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-animations, z-index

http://lucasdebelder.be/googledoodle/

I want to have the planet (bottom image) on top of the top image (the blue background/space). I have a main `div class:"center"` set on `'position: absolute'` and around both of those images is separately a div wrapped with `position: relative;` but somehow they don't want to go and sit on top of each other, I've also tried it with `z-index` but that doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the relevant code in the post please, don't just link to your site. Your site will change over time and without the original code in your post, the post is useless to the community when they search for this problem years from now and can't reference the original code. You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these properties the planeet_achtergrond class:

```
.planeet_achtergrond{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend nesting the two images in a div then adding a class to each image. Then use margin: 0 auto to center the div to the page. This is my solution:

```css
#googledoodle {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:512px;
  width:900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.galaxy {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.planet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 380px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="googledoodle">
 <img src="http://lucasdebelder.be/googledoodle/images/galaxy.png" width="900" class="galaxy">
 <img src="http://lucasdebelder.be/googledoodle/images/planeet.png" width="950" class="planet">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed all css. Here sample:

```
.center {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
.space_achtergrond {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
.planeet_achtergrond {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
}
form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

use **overflow:hidden** outer div.

if you want place divs inside a div with **position:absolute**, use **position:relative** for parent div.

if you want to stick a div bottom, use only **bottom:0**